# Max integer value of python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the max value of integer in python for 64-bit system.

I tried sys.maxsize and I tried incrementing the value by 1 and still showing type as int. If it is converted to long data type, why it is not appending L at the end. Also how to find the max value of long type?

```
sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
type(sys.maxsize +1)
<class 'int'>
sys.maxsize+1
9223372036854775808
```

Comment: Python 3 doesn't have `long` data type. The two integer types were unified into `int`, which is essentially equivalent of Python 2 `long`, i.e. an arbitrary-sized integer type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python3, value of an integer is not restricted by the number of bits and can expand to the limit of the available memory

```
print(100**100)
```

output:
   100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000